# windows mobile custom component

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm interested in creating custom menu component for windows mobile 6.0 instead of default one.
Can someone suggest some guides, tutorials, samples or something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about writing "Today" screen plugins?

Here's a tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839442

I found a forum post on MSDN about it that might be of interest too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/8c54119c-c31d-4569-ae94-6e54ecb4ece6/